# Driving two 2560x1440 displays with Lenovo T430 and 433715U ThinkPad Mini Dock Series 3

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I want to grab a second HP ZR2740w for use in my home office. I have a Lenovo T430 with an Intel HD4000 GPU, **not** the nVidia model.

The HP monitors come with Dual-Link DVI or DisplayPort for connectivity. The Lenovo dock has a single DisplayPort, a single-link DVI, and a VGA connector. The only output on the dock that supports 2560x1440 is the DisplayPort, which is in use by my current single monitor.

The options, as I see them, are:

1. Get a second monitor and use a DisplayPort to mini-DisplayPort cable and plug it directly into my laptop's mDP port. According to random forums on the Internet, this will work, but I can't find an official support statement from Lenovo on this. It also defeats the purpose of the dock.
2. Get a second monitor with a lower resolution and connect it to the dock's single-link DVI. This is a bummer, as there's a sweet deal going on near me for the HP monitor that I mentioned, and I already own one of them.
3. Get some kind of DisplayPort splitter. I've seen some talk that electrically, a single DP connector can support two devices at 2560x1440. Is this true? Will these devices work on the dock that I've mentioned?

Unfortunately, it's not possible to get a new dock. They are work-issued. Also, if there are any options that I've missed, feel free to chime in!

Comment: Hire a professional.

Comment: #3 is true, ***if*** the chipset supports daisy-chained displays. Last I knew AMD was the only manufacturer to support this, and people have reported problems with various drivers and whatnot.

Comment: @ChrisS I know you can daisy-chain thunderbolt displays, which are electrically similar (identical?) to DP when used for displays, and that Apple supports this on Intel HD4000-based notebooks. But I wouldn't be shocked to find out that they're using some special sauce to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up biting the bullet and doing option #1 with a DP to mDP cable and connecting directly to the laptop's mini-DisplayPort for the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with Matrox TripleHeadToGo devices.  I  think the effective mechanism is "present as a huge display, and chunk it down digitally".

They're reasonably expensive, Windows or Mac only, but do work quite well.  [I worked in a place a couple of years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/350080/what-concerns-are-there-with-putting-two-high-end-graphics-cards-in-one-pc) where every PC had 4+ displays, which was basically created by a dual-head graphics card, feeding a TripleHead device.

Answer (score 0):

Also owning a T430 I failed, getting out two video signals plus built-in Monitor by any means possible. Even at a lower 1920x1080. Using DVI+DP(->HDMI) with and without docking station.

Thus for Option 1+2 the answer is “no”, I think.

I did get lucky with a USB to HDMI adapter: „CM3 USB 2.0 to DVI, VGA or HDMI Adapter“. Sounds adventurous, but as long, as you are more into standing display content (web pages, code, text or small-window animation), and play your hd video stuff on the other (directly connected dp/hdmi) display, I hardly notice any lag. Costs around 50-80 USD. Done so in various home/work environments through a and without a docking station. [ The USB Monitor is a bit sturdy until it gets „recognized“ (unplug, wait, replug...), but when it works it's fantastic to have for someone like me with a triple screen fetish.]

Very recently, my attention has been driven to the possiblity of „daisy chaining“ for Display Port. (A more foreseen, less tricky approach than „splitting“ video signals in the old day, if I understand correctly). Haven't tested, though! See here:

http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/

Also search for displayport „hubs“, I am not sure, if daisy chaining has special expectations on your monitors.

Answer (score -1):

At home I run Built-in + External + External by connecting VGA directly to the computer than I bought JUA210 VGA to USB adapter.  $28 fix, bought it at BestBuy.  You can find them cheaper online.

http://www.j5create.com/our-products/external-video-adapters/jua210.html